# In jQuery, is prepend().hide().fadeIn() not so smooth?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

in jQuery, will the following be not so smooth?

```
$('<a href= ... ><img src= ...  /></a>').prependTo($('#someDiv')).hide().fadeIn()
```

Will it actually shows the added element for a split second, and then hide it, and then fadeIn ?

Then will the animation be not so smooth?

Is there any better method?

Or the following?

```
$('<a style="display:none" href= ... ><img src= ...  /></a>').prependTo($('#someDiv')).fadeIn()
```

or

```
$('<a href= ... ><img src= ...  /></a>').hide().prependTo($('#someDiv')).fadeIn()
```

**Update:** the original was

```
$('#someDiv').prepend('<a href= ><img src  /></a>').hide().fadeIn()
```

which actually may be hiding the `#someDiv` and then fading it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rearrange it a bit using [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/), like this:

```
$('<a href= ... ><img src= ...  /></a>').hide().prependTo('#someDiv').fadeIn();
```

This allows you to call [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) before adding it, so no visual artifacts.

Comment: ah, so prependTo("#someDiv") is the same as prependTo($('#someDiv')) ??

Comment: @Jian - Yep, it can take a selector directly :)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding and the fading its like running around the table :) Use the second method and set fadeIn with a "slow" parameter, like so:

```
$('#someDiv').prepend('<a style="display:none" href= ><img src  /></a>').fadeIn("slow");
```

And should be really smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

How about fading it first and then prepending it and only showing it then, quite smooth right?

```
$('#someDiv').fadeOut("fast").prepend('<a style="display:none" href= ><img src  /></a>').fadeIn("slow");
```